# Save data received from the site parse.com on the device

Tags: android, parse-platform

How can I save the data coming from parse.com within the android device?

I'm trying to save the data somewhere in the application for when you have no network, the customer can still get the data saved on the device.

I am using this code to make the list and is working, just missing the issue of saving data when you have no internet.

```
package com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

/**
 * Created by Rony Sueliton on 11/04/2015.
 */
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

public class Pizzarias extends ActionBarActivity {

 // Declare Variables
 Boolean bColorStatus = true;
 TextView status;
 ListView listview;
 List<ParseObject> ob;

 ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
 ListViewAdapterPizzarias adapter;
 private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_pizzarias);

 new RemoteDataTask().execute();

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_pizzarias, menu);

 //Os metodos abaixo são para mostrar o icone do aplicativo na action bar
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

 return true;
 }


 /*@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 onBackPressed();
 return true;
 }*/

 //RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
 private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
 super.onPreExecute();
 // Create a progressdialog
 mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Pizzarias.this);
 // Set progressdialog title
 mProgressDialog.setTitle("Carregando Pizzarias");
 // Set progressdialog message
 mProgressDialog.setMessage("Aguarde...");
 mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
 // Show progressdialog
 mProgressDialog.show();
 }

 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
 // Create the array
 worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();

 try {
 // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
 ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("GerenciarPizzariasPatos");

 // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
 // by ascending,

 query.orderByAscending("nome");

 ob = query.find();
 for (ParseObject country : ob) {
 WorldPopulation map = new WorldPopulation();
 map.setNome((String) country.get("nome"));
 map.setEndereco((String) country.get("endereco"));
 map.setTelefone((String) country.get("telefone"));
 map.setStatus((String) country.get("status"));
 worldpopulationlist.add(map);
 }
 } catch (ParseException e) {
 Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return null;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
 // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
 listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewpizzarias);
 // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
 adapter = new ListViewAdapterPizzarias(Pizzarias.this,
 worldpopulationlist);
 // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
 listview.setAdapter(adapter);
 // Close the progressdialog
 mProgressDialog.dismiss();
 }
 }
}
```

////

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this, "xxx", "xxx");

        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this
        // line.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    }

}
```

Comment: [Take your app offline with parse local database](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/take-your-app-offline-with-parse-local-datastore/)

Comment: @Vivart. I've done it and did not work, I wonder how it would be the correct way to implement within my code because I've tried many ways, not managed.

Comment: May be you can have a database in your app that saves the data and serves you when the internet is off. Just refresh your data in your database for some interval to have the updated data.

Comment: @RonySueliton did u enable local database using
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext()); in Application class?

Comment: @Vivart. This `(getApplicationContext ());` you quoted I did not, just put the `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);` where he spoke in the tutorial that would have to be laid, but had already placed and has not worked.

Comment: I put the class in question above.

Comment: @RonySueliton The code merely fetches data. Where's the part that saves it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `pin(map);` after `worldpopulationlist.add(map);` and add to logic that will check whether connection is available and would enable `query.fromLocalDatastore()` option in case of unavailable connection before executing query

Answer (score 0):

I changed my line of code to this, I tried to use a tutorial of internet parse.com blog, but is giving an error GET, underlined with a red line.

I tried to use an example of the site: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/take-your-app-offline-with-parse-local-datastore/

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();


        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            //ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("GerenciarPizzariasPatos");
            String objectId = "GFiBnjCE4v";
            ParseObject feed = ParseQuery.get(objectId); // error GET // Online ParseQuery result
            feed.fetch();
            feed.put("fechado", true);
            feed.saveEventually();

            //ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GerenciarPizzariasPatos");
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.get("GerenciarPizzariasPatos") // error GET 
                    .fromLocalDatastore()
                    .whereEquals("fechado", true)
                    .findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                            // "feed" ParseObject will be returned in the list of results
                        }
                    });

            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending,

            query.orderByAscending("nome");

            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                WorldPopulation map = new WorldPopulation();
                map.setNome((String) country.get("nome"));
                map.setEndereco((String) country.get("endereco"));
                map.setTelefone((String) country.get("telefone"));
                map.setStatus((String) country.get("status"));
                worldpopulationlist.add(map);

            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @Oleg Osipenko. I made a change in my code, trying to use the tutorial, but I received an error in get, which is underlined with a red line and this error when compiling: `Error:(100, 46) error: non-static method get(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
where T is a type-variable:
T extends ParseObject declared in class ParseQuery`

Comment: @async. Take a look now what I'm trying to implement.

Comment: @Yarh. You could take a look at my question?